# Android wear doesn't start thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, wear-os

I'm building an application with my team for a robot car to let it drive controlled by a mobile device. It works perfectly on my phone, but now that I've ported the app to Android Wear, the thread that lets me connect to a server on my Raspberry Pi doesn't work. Is there a way to get this thread working?

Code:

```
public class SocketConnect {

static DataOutputStream dOut;
static Socket socket;

public static void connect() {
    System.out.println("Got to Connect");
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                socket = new Socket("192.168.2.9", 8899);
                System.out.println("Trying at 2.9");
                dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }.start();

}
....further code
```

Logcat error: http://pastebin.com/0BtF27p8
(couldn't get it to format nice in the editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems with your approach:

1. [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) - you can't do network operations on the main (UI) thread on Android 4.0+ devices
2. Android Wear devices cannot directly connect to **any** internet address - you have to use the [Wearable Data Layer](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) to send information to the phone app and have it connect/pass information to a server

In many cases, including what you'd want to do for controlling a robot car, you'd probably want to use [messages](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to transfer a lightweight command from the Watch to your phone app.